# How Can I repeat a System Sound

Tags: ios, audio, system-sounds

I want to repeat the sounds that are send to this method?

```
- (void) playSound:(CFURLRef)soundFileURLRef {
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    OSStatus errorCode = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    if (errorCode != 0) {

    }else{
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    }
}
```

I've seen answers on how this is made using numberOfRepeats. But I can't fit it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `AVAudioPlayer`:

```
- (void) playSound:(CFURLRef)soundFileURLRef {
    NSError* sndErr;        
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[ AVAudioPlayer alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)soundFileURLRef error:(&sndErr) ];

    // at this point player has a retain count of 1. you should save it 
    // somewhere like a class member variable so you can stop the playing
    // and release the object later. Under ARC, you must have a strong reference
    // to the object so that it doesn't get released when this function goes out
    // of scope.

    if (sndErr != nil) {
        player.numberOfLoops = -1; // infinite number of loops. call stop when you want to stop.
        [player play];
    }
}
```